# Steps to consume REST Web Service within Jdeveloper

Tags: web-services, rest

Can anyone help to provide the steps for making a POST request to JAX-WS REST url with the XML as the body of the POST request using Jdeveloper?

Basically consuming the JAX-WS REST service within SOAP based web service...

Thanks in advance and please give some ideas and document for reference...

Comment: Did you tried our friend google?

Comment: I try to check a lot but cannot find simpler answer....

Comment: I have created a web service in ERP Jd edwards. This web servie will get the input from Sales Order like order no and order status....now I have to consume the REST service into my web service and pass this order no and status as POST and retrieve the response from REST, success or failure....based on that i need to update back the communication failure.... this is overall picture.....I have JD Edwards web service in place now how to consume other REST service i get stuck...could you please guide me....

Comment: 1) JAX-RS is not supported, currently JAX-RPC and JAX-WS (TR 9.1.2 onwards) With JD Edwards EnterpriseOne Tools Release 9.1 
2) JDE is not supporting the "Rest-based webservices" on the BSSV Server and never tested with a Proxy also.But You can try exploring in the Jdeveloper IDE. May be you will able to develop a Consumer that consumes REST using Jdeveloper, 
But Now the Question is How to deploy that Consumer on the BSSV Server? You may not be able to do it. It may contain any new anotations or new Classes which cannot be built by current BSSV package build process.